# Firebase 9.0.0- How to see if user is logged in with AuthStateListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

With Google's Firebase AuthStateListener, I'm not sure how to detect if the Auth token has expired. I'm using email and password authentication and the listener works correctly for the first time users open the app and logs them in automatically on subsequent app launches.

Problem arises when their login token expires and the user should have to re-authenticate. The AuthStateListener just logs them in, but the Firebase service denies them access because their token has expired.

My Listener Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selector);

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                changeToNextFragment();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are not currently logged in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                changeToLogin();
            }
        }
        };
```

And the listener is called here:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuth);
}
```

What is the appropriate test on the FirebaseAuth Object to see if the token has expired?

Comment: In the 3.x SDK the auth token should automatically be refreshed every hour, without requiring code from your side. Are you saying that your users are getting errors because their token expires? If so, can you post the error/stack trace?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I'm in a similar scenario. I have persistence enabled and the user gets automatically logged-in after a couple of hours of inactivity (emulator shutdown so no automatic token refresh). Once logged in the user can interact with the local db (setValues and changeEventListeners). But local change events never get to show at the console (and vice-versa). 
I'm getting this log message:
"PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: expired_token (Auth token is expired)".
Everything comes to normal after forcing sign-out and sign-in.

Comment: I should mention that the app was behaving as expected before the migration process. And that I had set at the old console a session time of 10years.